# .NET Find Windows Sleep Settings

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, sleep

I would like to find out what the current windows sleep mode setting is i.e. Is it switched on and what is the timer period. Any ideas?

My preferences (in order) are:

1. .NET Managed Code
2. API
3. Read Registry Value

Comment: I'm also very interested in the answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where it is stored in the registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\PowerCfg] "CurrentPowerPolicy"="2"     
Power Scheme (Default="0")
  "0" = Home/Office Desk
 "1" = Portable/Laptop
 "2" = Presentation
 "3" = Always On
 "4" = Minimal Power Management
 "5" = Max Battery
```

Then Access it:

```
RegistryKey key= Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\PowerCfg", true);
var value = key.GetValue("CurrentPowerPolicy", 0);
```

There is also a key called Policies that is `REG_BINARY` that stores all the specific information. You can use the example on this page to read it: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/13312/registry-access-for-regbinary-values.aspx

Comment: This only tells me the power scheme though, not whether sleep mode is enabled

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.